# Laravel 5 Sort data in Alphabetical Order

Tags: php, sql, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.4

What is the best approach to display data in Alphabetical order using Laravel. what is the best way to querying for data for this type of task?

This is the example what i wanted!

[image: Example Alphabetical Order List]

is it good to use [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) or is there any best way to do this?

Comment: `best` is always a subjective term and therefore isn't a good fit for questions on Stackoverflow. Is there a specific problem you're facing? Collections are just wrappers around `arrays()`. So I don't see any reason why they wouldn't be a good fit for your particular solution, as a list would still need to be represented in a matrice of some type.

Comment: IMO, `best` would be to sort alphabetically in your query. And then I'd use a `collection` to group by the first letter of each term. If you post your code, you will likely get more help.

Comment: I will post the code later for sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok Found an answer!!

```
$collection = App\User::orderBy('name')->get();

$grouped = $collection->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return substr($item->name, 0, 1);
});
```